# Telegram bot Java

Tags: java, telegram

Реализую телеграм бота для парсинга. Прокси работает, бот отвечает на слова, а вот парсинг работает не как ожидается и не выводит на экран почему?

**class Main**

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultBotOptions;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Main {
    // private static String PROXY_HOST = "87.214.0.47" /* proxy host */;
    // private static Integer PROXY_PORT = 3128 /* proxy port */;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApiContextInitializer.init();
            TelegramBotsApi telegramm = new TelegramBotsApi();

            DefaultBotOptions options = ApiContext
                    .getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);
            options.setProxyHost("166.62.83.129");
            options.setProxyPort(20333);
            //Select proxy type: [HTTP|SOCKS4|SOCKS5] (default: NO_PROXY)
            options.setProxyType(DefaultBotOptions.ProxyType.SOCKS5);

            telegramm.registerBot(new Bot(options));
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**class Bot**

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultBotOptions;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    KapperBook kapperBook = new KapperBook();
    private long chat_id;

    public Bot(DefaultBotOptions options) {
        super(options);
    }

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        update.getUpdateId();
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
        chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        sendMessage.setText(input(update.getMessage().getText()));

        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "@KupperMSCBot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "787571455:AAFl9vffyhKqLq6ADadWJg2ByzQFMBifcno";
    }

    public String getInfoKapperBook() {
        String info = kapperBook.getTitle()
                + "\nЛига " + kapperBook.getGeners()
                + "\n\nОписание " + kapperBook.getDescription()
                + "\n\nКоличестов лайков\n" + kapperBook.getOrating_res();
        return info;
    }

    String input(String msg) {
        if (msg.contains("Ставка")) {
            return getInfoKapperBook();
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**class KapperBook**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class KapperBook {
    private Document document;

    public KapperBook() {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://vprognoze.ru/forecast/pro/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return document.title();
    }

    public String getOrating_res() {
        //   Element element = document.getElementById("orating_res"); // лайки
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("orating_res");
        return elements.text();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("news_box");
        //Element element = document.getElementById("news_box"); // описание
        return elements.text();
    }

    public String getGeners() {
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("championship"); //лига
        return elements.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за корявый вопрос т.к. первый раз здесь. Суть в следующем реализую телеграм бота для парсинга. Прокси рабочии. бот отвечает на слова, а вот парсинг не делает и не выводит на экран почему?

Comment: Как ожидается и что он выводит? Вы отладчиком пользовались? В каком месте вы получаете не то, что ожидаете?

Comment: мар 08, 2019 3:00:23 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Connection timed out: connect
мар 08, 2019 3:00:23 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443         
Вот такая вот у меня ошибка!

Comment: BotFather ведь вам сказал "никому не сообщайте свой токен"... А вы?

Answer (score 0):

При попытке подключится через `Jsoup` из коробки по указанному вами адресу, вылетает исключение:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=307, URL=https://vprognoze.ru/forecast/pro/
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
    at ua.spoon.Application.main(Application.java:27)
```

На en SO есть вопрос на эту [тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412113/jsoup-error-307-when-trying-to-access-a-page)

> HTTP status code 307 is not an error, it's an information saying that
>   the server is making a temporary redirect to another page.

Вольный перевод:

> HTTP status code 307 это не код ошибки, а информация о том, что сервер 
>   сервер делает временное перенаправление на другую страницу.